# Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError) when try to insert data into collection on Atlast server

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I am creating a mongodb using mongoDB Atlas. Everything seems to be fine. When I ran the program, the server connected successfully. However, when I tried to insert data into the collection, it gave me the error "Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError)". I read on another post that said I have to use a different database name but that still didn't work. I am very new to this so any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code

```
public class DbController2<DBObject> {
MongoClientURI uri;
MongoClient mongoClient;
MongoDatabase database;
MongoCollection<Document> collection;

public DbController2() {
    uri = new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb://dbEfish:PASSWORD@cluster0-shard-00-00-klemt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-klemt.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-klemt.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true");

    mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
    database = mongoClient.getDatabase("eFishDB");
    collection = database.getCollection("controlVar");
}

public Document toDBObject(String key, String[] dataPoints) {
    return  new Document("_id", key)
            .append("Water Level", dataPoints[0])
            .append("Water Temperature", dataPoints[1])
            .append("pH Level", dataPoints[2])
            .append("Nitrate Level", dataPoints[3])
            .append("Oxygen Level", dataPoints[4])
            .append("Ammonia Level", dataPoints[5])
            .append("Light Intensity", dataPoints[6])
            .append("Air Temperature", dataPoints[7]);
}

public void insert(String key, String[] dataPoints) {
    //((DBCollection) collection).insert((com.mongodb.DBObject[]) this.toDBObject(key, dataPoints));
    collection.insertOne(this.toDBObject(key, dataPoints));
}
```

}

Here is the error log:
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4}] to cluster0-shard-00-00-klemt.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='dbEfish', source='admin', password=, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:173)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$300(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:152)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:398)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:424)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:194)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:961)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:495)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:479)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:473)
    at DbController2.insert(DbController2.java:37)
    at EFishGreen$4.actionPerformed(EFishGreen.java:131)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'bad auth Authentication failed.' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-klemt.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0, "errmsg": "bad auth Authentication failed.", "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:187)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:67)
    ... 59 more

Comment: You included your database's password in this question -- you'll likely want to update it

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so tired and frustrated I completely forgot about it.

Comment: That's an authentication error, and it basically means your username and password are incorrect or at least not found within the `authSource`. Note also that `authSource` is **optional** and should not be required where the space is in fact `admin` ( as it should be ) AND where you do not include a database namespace on the URI. So remove the `test` from the URI, and check your credentials. Also, there should be no need to not use the `mongodb+srv` form of the URI with a modern driver release. If your driver is older then I strongly suggest upgrading and using the modern URI form.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific driver & version you are using. As noted in the error log you provided, there is an authentication error which suggests you have an issue with the driver or credentials provided. Note: I hope you've [configured an appropriate whitelist](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) to limit connections to your Atlas deployment. Even so, I would recommend changing your password as it is still exposed in the edit history for this question.

Answer (score 5):

If MOngoDb atlas cloud credential and cloud details [IP/URL] is correct then THis is problem of driver that you have selected for connecting application. 
I faced same problem, the root cause mismatch version of driver in application and mongodb connection string.

**mongodb:**//testatlasCloud:sedXhdsghgK24RGJxF@firstvm-shard-00-00-n6ojx.mongodb.net:27017,firstvm-shard-00-01-n6ojx.mongodb.net:27017,firstvm-shard-00-02-n6ojx.mongodb.net:27017/firstvmDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=firstvm-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority");

mongodb+srv:// is not working for me because I am using old mongo driver version.