# Error: MongoError: bad auth: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

You might be trying to tell me to "change my password" or "remove brackets, these <>"
I have done both. I have made sure that the password I'm using is correct.
Here is the URI:

```
mongodb+srv://user:pass@notlbot.iclv0tm.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

no, my username isnt 'user' and my password also is not 'pass'
I don't know what to do from here, though it may be important to note I am trying to connect from a Linodes server. I'm using AWS to host Atlas.

```
     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
     at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
     at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
     at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22) 
     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)   
     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
     ok: 0,
     code: 8000,
     codeName: 'AtlasError'
 }
```

Comment: bad auth means auth has failed. So the username or password is incorrect. I would recommend connecting from any regular machine (like from your local machine) to ensure that credentials you use is correct

Comment: @dododo... I have. EVERYTHING is correct.

Comment: also see atlas recommendations how to connect to your cluster. You may look at x509 certificate instead username/password

Comment: @dododo Ok. I've tried certificate, and it seems to have been working. However, I get an error simply titled "Atlas Error" Yes, everything is in order..

Comment: It looks unlikely that you receive only `Atlas Error` without more details

Comment: just because you don't understand this `gibberish then code: 8000`, it does mean that it doesn't make sense. When you ask a question you should provide all possible details

Comment: other than what I suggested in first comment, I can suggest looking at: https://newbedev.com/mongodb-atlas-bad-auth-authentication-failed-code-8000, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666655/command-failed-with-error-8000-atlaserror-when-try-to-insert-data-into-collect